# Triangle construction procedure

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

Two lines $L1,L_2$ pass through a common point $O. $ $L_2$  goes through points $P$ and $Q$. How to construct a circle through $P,Q$ to be  tangent to $L_1?$

In a particular case, at the tangent point $T$ we have similar triangles  $OTP,   OQT. $

Comment: Are you sure $P,Q$ are not on $L_1$, with both on the same side of $L_2$ (impossible if on opposite sides)? It's then an Appollonius LPP problem, e.g. http://gogeometry.com/school-college/1/p1032-apollonius-points-circle-tangent-line-lpp-math.htm.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but you could use my answer for [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345106/construction-of-a-circle-through-a-point-and-tangent-to-angle/1345254#1345254) and adapt it. Use the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{PQ }$ rather than the angle bisector in my answer. A fuller answer would also handle the case where that line is parallel to line $L_1$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am using this as a support for another current topic  locus of points in a line  which I am sure you would find interesting.

Comment: Does the construction method allow for measurement and the calculation of square roots, or is it purely compass-and-straightedge?

Comment: Compass/ straight edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is to locate $X$ (which is your $T$) on $L_1$ such that it is the point of contact of the required circle that passes through $P$ and $Q$ on $L_2$.

By “power of a point”, $OX^2 = OP.OQ$. The RHS and the LHS of this equation are respectively a rectangle whose sides are $OP \times OQ$ and a square whose sides are $OX$ (and the 2 figures are equal in area).

[image]

The way of finding $OX$ is:-

1. By drawing the red dotted circle, locate $Q’$ on $PO$ extended such that $OQ = OQ’$.
2. On $OQ’$, locate $M$, the midpoint of $PQ’$.
3. Using $M$ as center with $MP$ as radius, draw the green dotted circle.
4. AT $O$, erect the perpendicular $OX’$ cutting the green dotted circle at $X’$.

After the above construction, the power of $O$ w.r.t. the green dotted circle is $OX’^2 = OQ’.OP$.

The final step is to draw the blue dotted circle (centered at $O$, $OX’$ as radius). It cuts $L_1$ at $X$.

$XPQ$ is the required circle.

The answer to your last question is yes (and always).

The blue dotted circle cuts $L_1$ at point $Y$ too. The black dotted circle passing through $Y, P, Q$ also meets the requirement.  Below is an updated version according to @RoryDaulton 's suggestion:-

[image]

Comment: +1 but two suggestions. 1) There are *two* circles that meet the requirements. The point of tangency of the second circle is the *other* intersection of your blue dotted circle with line $L_1$. You could easily add that to your diagram and description. 2) Your diagram makes it appear that point $Q$ is necessarily on the line through point $X$ and perpendicular to line $L_1$, but that is not the case. I suggest you move point $Q$ or line $L_1$ to make that more clear.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good findings. Comment noted. Need to fix that later because the original picture file was not properly saved.